# Summation over square root upper bound

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that  summation 1/root k less than 2 root n -1 
I am getting the upper bound like (root (n)-root (n-1))
Please help

Comment: Please attempt to use MathJax and show your work.

Comment: Please edit it don't know latex

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}} = 2(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})$ for $k > 1$.

Comment: S, in case you ever look at this again, I put pretty clear steps, in my answer, on how to complete an induction proof.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know what you are doing: the sum, minus $\sqrt n$ decreases. The sum, minus $\sqrt{n+1}$ must be a little lower, and increases. Therefore the two adjusted columns approach a common limit, approximately $-1.46 \; \;.$

I just checked, as an induction proof, it is not necessary to know any calculus to show that the right hand column really is decreasing, therefore remaining below $-1$  For notation, let
$$ R_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \; \frac{1}{\sqrt k}.  $$
Let us call the middle column, which gives a lower bound for the limit,
$$ L_n = R_n - 2 \sqrt {n+1} \; . $$
The right hand column gives an upper bound, call it
$$ U_n = R_n - 2 \sqrt n \; .   $$
Induction is fairly similar in both cases, we just need prove
$$ L_{n+1} - L_n > 0 \; ,  $$
$$ U_{n+1}- U_n < 0 \; .   $$
For the two induction proofs, just define  $x = \sqrt {n+1}$ and write the indicated differences in terms of $x,$ then show the $L$ difference comes out positive, while the $U$ difference comes out negative. For one proof, you need $\sqrt {n+2} = \sqrt {x^2 + 1},$ for the other proof  $\sqrt {n} = \sqrt {x^2 - 1} \; .$

```
Wed Jan  3 10:37:34 PST 2018
    n     sum of 1/sqrt(k)     sum - 2 sqrt(n+1)      sum - 2 sqrt(n)
    1    1                    -1.82842712474619     -1
    2    1.707106781186547    -1.756994833951207    -1.121320343559643
    3    2.284457050376173    -1.715542949623827    -1.179644564761581
    4    2.784457050376173    -1.687678904623406    -1.215542949623827
    5    3.231670645876131    -1.667308839690225    -1.240465309123449
    6    3.639918936339994    -1.651583685789187    -1.259060549226362
    7    4.017883409349222    -1.638970840143159    -1.27361921277996
    8    4.371436799942495    -1.628563200057505    -1.285417449549885
    9    4.704770133275828    -1.619785187060931    -1.295229866724172
   10    5.020997899292666    -1.612251681418133    -1.303557421044093
   11    5.32250924387043     -1.605693986405079    -1.31074033684037
   12    5.611184378465243    -1.599918172462735    -1.317018851810266
   13    5.888534476577857    -1.594780296970026    -1.322568074350121
   14    6.155795718490282    -1.590170973924552    -1.327519055057601
   15    6.413994608237443    -1.586005391762557    -1.331972084177391
   16    6.663994608237443    -1.582216642997878    -1.336005391762557
   17    6.906530233273776    -1.578751140964793    -1.339681017961545
   18    7.142232493669292    -1.575565393412056    -1.343048880569278
   19    7.371648227539854    -1.572623682459305    -1.346149659541494
   20    7.595255025289833    -1.569896364621846    -1.349016884709326
   21    7.813472915525826    -1.567358604121034    -1.351678474385854
   22    8.026673631881437    -1.564989414744002    -1.354157887765423
   23    8.235188045938511    -1.562770925194201    -1.356475000686928
   24    8.439312191170442    -1.560687808829558    -1.358646779962269
   25    8.639312191170442    -1.558726836015127    -1.360687808829558
   26    8.835428326308625    -1.556876519104639    -1.362610700876944
   27    9.027878416038501    -1.555126828219862    -1.364426429374763
   28    9.216860652543115    -1.553468961725892    -1.366144591715248
   29    9.402555990720167    -1.551895159383156    -1.367773623548841
   30    9.585130176555221    -1.550398549104822    -1.369320973548101
   31    9.764735478581997    -1.548973020402764    -1.370793247078046
   32    9.941512173878634    -1.547613119197424    -1.372196325106128
   33    10.11558982983433    -1.546313959856271    -1.373535463241726
   34    10.28708841497684    -1.545071151222393    -1.374815374713762
   35    10.45611926592254    -1.543880734077458    -1.37604030027669
    n     sum of 1/sqrt(k)     sum - 2 sqrt(n+1)      sum - 2 sqrt(n)
Wed Jan  3 10:37:34 PST 2018
```

Comment: Prove it mathematically